# Drop frames from YUY to get lower frame rates

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I would like to encode a YUV file using FFmpeg in three different frame rates: 60, 30 and 15 FPS. The capture frame rate of the video sequence is 60 FPS, so it plays most naturally at this rate. My goal is to keep the video duration (10s) the same for all three frame rates, and subsample/discard the frames while encoding the lower frames (30 and 15). However, when I try to achieve this using

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s:v 1920x1080 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i Test.yuv -c:v h264_nvenc -preset hq -rc cbr -profile:v main -b:v 10M out.mp4
```

the video duration doubles to 20s, and similarly for 15 FPS it goes up to 40s.

How can I instead drop the frames from the original YUV to keep the duration same and temporally subsample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to specify the input *and* the output framerate, otherwise it just assumes they are equal and no frames are dropped/duplicated.

I think your command will then look something like this:

```bsh
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s:v 1920x1080 -r 60 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i Test.yuv -c:v h264_nvenc -preset hq -rc cbr -profile:v main -b:v 10M -r 15 out.mp4
```

Comment: This worked. And sorry, of course the output should not be a YUV again but a container format like MP4. Fixed the question.